# Unable to extract all paragraph tags from HTML document using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all `<p></p>` from an HTML document using Html Agility Pack.
However, when I try below, all the nodes are null.

```cs
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\Webs\test.html");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

foreach ( var paragraph in nodes ) { 
    Console.WriteLine($"paragraph {paragraph.InnerText}");
}

Html

    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
     <p>I am a paragraph</p>
     <p>I am a paragraph</p>
     <h1>I am an H1</h1>
     <p>I am a paragraph</p>
     <p>I am a paragraph</p>
     <p>I am a paragraph</p>
     <h1>I am an H1</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p");`? If that still does not work, please provide the html source.

Comment: No, the doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p"); does not work.  I have provided the html doc above now.

Comment: Works here. Install the correct nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack - and perhaps write `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();` to ensure you use the HtmlDocument of the package and nothing else. Also check if the file path is correct (is doc empty?).